# How to store text and formatting separately?

Tags: api, text, formatting, logic

Let's say we have online text editor like google docs. There is a page with a formatted text there. Is it possible for backend to store the formatting and the text separately, without using markdown or html?

For example, the text is:

"Max **brushes** his teeth twice a day:

1. In the morning
2. In the evening"

Backend message would be like:

```
Text: "Max brushes his teeth twice a day:In the morningIn the evening"
Formatting:
    4-11-bold
    34-enter
    34-48-numberedList
    48-enter
    48-62-numberedList
```

Where numbers is number of symbols to pass to apply formatting. Frontend will be parsing it to display for a reader.

What would be the limitations for such approach, except for obvious necessity to recalculate values for every text insert/delete?